# class property not found at runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a library project, and its dll I have used in a website.
Everything was working perfectly, recently i have added this in TFS
and then after when i added new propery in library project class, i am able to get it in website with intelligence , but when I tried to build website, it throws error for newly added property not found, and it throws error in error window and then disappear, 
I have all tried with deleting and re-adding project library dll many times, restarting visual studio, restarting machine, 
But still i am stuck on it.

any advise.

Thanks

Comment: Could it be that your dll is added to GAC? It is the first place where runtime looks for assemblies

Comment: sorry @dotnetom , how can i remove it from GAC, if it is there?